# Facing error 'RNGestureHandlerModule.State' with React Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am new to react native. While implementing react-navigation, I am facing a strange problem. I am getting an error on iOS simulator "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'RNGestureHandlerModule.State'). Nowhere I am using gesture recognizer in the app.

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      createStackNavigator({
        Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
      })
    )
    }
}
```

HomeScreen is a simple class:

```
export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View>
                <Text style={{marginTop: 80}}>Thi sis test</Text>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

I am using react-native CLI. While installing react-navigation I am getting several warnings

```
ankur:MyGithub ankurprakash$ cd /Volumes/Glen/MyGithub/navigationSample 
ankur:navigationSample ankurprakash$ npm install --save react-navigation@latest
npm WARN rm not removing /Volumes/Glen/MyGithub/navigationSample/node_modules/.bin/sane as it wasn't installed by /Volumes/Glen/MyGithub/navigationSample/node_modules/sane
npm WARN rm not removing /Volumes/Glen/MyGithub/navigationSample/node_modules/.bin/uuid as it wasn't installed by /Volumes/Glen/MyGithub/navigationSample/node_modules/uuid
npm WARN rm not removing /Volumes/Glen/MyGithub/navigationSample/node_modules/.bin/json5 as it wasn't installed by /Volumes/Glen/MyGithub/navigationSample/node_modules/json5
npm WARN rm not removing /Volumes/Glen/MyGithub/navigationSample/node_modules/.bin/jsesc as it wasn't installed by /Volumes/Glen/MyGithub/navigationSample/node_modules/jsesc
npm WARN rm not removing /Volumes/Glen/MyGithub/navigationSample/node_modules/.bin/jest as it wasn't installed by /Volumes/Glen/MyGithub/navigationSample/node_modules/jest-cli
npm WARN rm not removing /Volumes/Glen/MyGithub/navigationSample/node_modules/.bin/esparse as it wasn't installed by /Volumes/Glen/MyGithub/navigationSample/node_modules/esprima
npm WARN rm not removing /Volumes/Glen/MyGithub/navigationSample/node_modules/.bin/esvalidate as it wasn't installed by /Volumes/Glen/MyGithub/navigationSample/node_modules/esprima
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this once:

1. remove node_modules and package-lock.json
2. npm install
3. npm install --save react-navigation
4. npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler
5. react-native link

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I need to remake the sample because from time to time, I get strange errors in react native. Sometimes Development server 500 on Android, while same code runs in iOS, ENOENT error. How to deal with all this. is there something like Xcode or android studio IDE for react-native. Make development smooth.

Comment: Also, can you guide me why to install "react-native-gesture-handler"? I wanted to install react-navigation. What is the link between the two?

Comment: @AnkurPrakash `react-navigation` requires `react-native-gesture-handler` as you can see from the installation instructions https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/getting-started.html#installation